# Unable to upload a file with Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, file, django-templates

Trying to upload a file using Django and Jquery. Here Jquery code

```
function editProfileData(){
        $("#editProfileForm").submit(save_data);
        function save_data() {
            $.post("/Profile/profile/editProfile/", { 
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
                'UserName':$('#id_UserName').val(), 
                'UserSurname':$('#id_UserSurname').val(),
                'UserEmail':$('#id_UserEmail').val(), 
                'UserAlternateEmail':$('#id_UserAlternateEmail').val(),
                'UserTelephone':$('#id_UserTelephone').val(),
                'UserCity':$('#id_UserCity').val(),
                'File':$('#id_UserAvatar').val().name
            },
            .....................................
```

When I try to upload a file then it fails. When you check request.POST["File"] and I get the following path "C:\fakepath\bg.png". When they check request.FILES["File"] then no data. How to send a file from Yyaueri controller.

That form of HTML

```
<form id="editProfileForm" action="{% url "editProfile" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}

      <input type="file" id="id_UserAvatar" name="File"/>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Edit"/>           
</form>
```

How do I request Jquery can have data request.FILES["File"]?

Comment: Do you need to support IE6-9? What you are trying to do is not supported in IE<10 and for the rest of the browsers requires special syntax involving the `window.formData` class.

Comment: I have IE 10 . But I can send the file to the controller and processed with requests.FILES['File']